# How to join data from correlated queries using aggregate functions?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
userActions:
id | uId | goodAction | actionOverridden | dateAdded
```

I wrote a query to get:

- The number of good actions (rows where `goodAction = 1`)
- The number of bad actions (rows where `goodAction = 0`)
- The number of actions that were overridden (rows where `actionOverridden = 1`)

```
SELECT

(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM userActions ua
WHERE ua.goodAction = 0 AND ua.dateAdded > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 year AND ua.uId = 520) badActions,

(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM userActions ua
WHERE ua.goodAction = 1 AND ua.dateAdded > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 year AND ua.uId = 520) goodActions,

(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM userActions ua
WHERE ua.actionOverridden = 1 AND ua.dateAdded > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 year AND ua.uId = 520) actionOverrides
```

The above query gets the data for the user with ID `520`, but I want to get this information for all users. With the above query, I would need to get a list of users in PHP, then loop over the list and execute the above query, injecting the user ID.

How can the above query be modified to make it retrieve the data for all users?

I know the `AND ua.uId = 520` condition will need to be removed from the subqueries, and I think a `GROUP BY ua.uId` will be used outside the subqueries, but I'm not sure exactly what to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use CASE expression instead of all this correlated queries, and use group by to get the results for all users like this:

```
SELECT t.uID,
       sum(case when t.goodAction = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as badActions,
       sum(case when t.goodAction = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as goodActions,
       sum(case when t.actionOverridden = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as actionOverrides
FROM userActions t
WHERE t.dateAdded > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 year
GROUP BY t.uID
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine COUNT and NULLIF and group by uID:

```
SELECT t.uID,
       COUNT(NULLIF(1, t.goodAction)) AS badActions,
       COUNT(NULLIF(0, t.goodAction)) AS goodActions,
       COUNT(NULLIF(0, t.actionOverridden)) AS actionOverrides
FROM userActions t
WHERE t.dateAdded > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 year
GROUP BY t.uID;
```